# One word adjective for "the owner of" and "shared with me"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm not a native English speaker and have to organize accounts into three distinctive sets:

1. The owner of
2. Shared by me (to others)
3. Shared with me (by others)

I need to give these sets proper **one word** names

1. *Own* or *owned*?
2. *Shared*
3. ??? Can't use *Shared* again...

I also don't like the *Own/Owned* name because especially the latter relates to being possessed. The only one I actually am ok with is *Shared* for those accounts that I've shared with others.

### Questions

I'm looking for one words/adjectives of each of these sets:

1. What would be the name for third set of accounts? Could *accredited* work in this context.
2. What better synonym could I use for *own* or *owned* to still be applicable to accounts?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because choosing identifier names for programming purposes is explicitly forbidden by our Help Center.

Comment: Rephrased the question to distance it from being programming related, because it's not really... It's purely banking business related.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik This is a [tag:single-word-request]. Please add that tag. Also in order to have it reopened, you also need to include an example of a sentence where you would use the word in the body of the question. Also, while many S.W.Rs. have the normal research requirements waived, due to the difficulty of finding a word from its concept, use of [E.L.U. as a thesaurus is discouraged](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), so it would also be helpful if you came up with [a list of synonyms from a thesaurus](http://tinyurl.com/pv84eho) and reasons you have dismissed those options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess something like that would work :

1. My accounts
2. My shared accounts
3. Other shared accounts

You can swap "Other" for something like "outer", "external"...

I think you won't be able to get rid of "shared" in 2. and 3. as it is the most relevant word here.

> **Edit :**
>
> As a one-word adjective
>
> 1. Owned
> 2. Shared
> 3. Assigned
>
> Assigned isn't really on point, but the word you want here is "shared" too. There's no reason for them to have a different name, as they're the same but from a different point of view.

Comment: Could these be provided as single words (I suppose adjectives)?